# How can sanitize $_FILES['haq_slider'] field

Tags: plugins, plugin-development

I have a function

```
function haqSliderHandleUpload() {
    global $haq_settings, $haqSliderImage;

    //  upload the image
    $sliderfile = $_FILES['haq_slider'];
    $upload = wp_handle_upload($sliderfile, 0);
    extract($upload);
    $uploadDirPath = str_replace(basename($file), '', $url);
    list($imageWidth, $imageHeight) = getimagesize($file);     }
```

I want to SANITIZE this field  $sliderfile = $_FILES['haq_slider'];
How can i do it

Answer (score 2):

You don't say where this code is running - for users or just for admins. Here are a few tips, taken heavily from this article on [Wordfence](https://www.wordfence.com/learn/how-to-prevent-file-upload-vulnerabilities/).

The first check you can run is [current_user_can](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/current_user_can/) to see if the current user is allowed to upload files using:

```
if(current_user_can('upload_files')) { ....
```

Next you can use [wp_check_filetype](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_check_filetype/) to see if it's a valid extension.

```
$fileInfo = wp_check_filetype(basename($_FILES['haq_slider']['name']));
if (!empty($fileInfo['ext'])) {
   // This file is valid
} else {
   // Invalid file
}
```

The final test that Wordfence suggest is a call to PHPs [getimagesize](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php) which will return `FALSE` if it fails to read a valid image file.

```
if (!@getimagesize($_FILES['haq_slider']['tmp_name']))
   wp_die(__('An invalid image was supplied.'));
```